# Set Laravel Specific Session Variable to expire after some time

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-variables

Im working on the Statistics page on my site,
and I need to keep the general session Variables to normal duration (ex: 120 min)
But I also want to store some of my Variables so I wont have to do 8 SQL queries every page reload
for example I want to save the user posts count for each of the past 30 days but its something that changes often so want to save it only for 10 minutes 
How can I make only specific Variables from the session to be removed after 10 minutes but keep the other alive?

I've thought about saving the last refresh time and every reload check if its been 10 minutes

```
Session::put('lastRefresh',  Carbon::now()->timestamp);
```

In Cache I would just do it

```
Cache::put('posts',  $posts, 10);
```

But its unique to each user so I can't
And some times its just a big array (90 Items for 90 Days) 
So I can't use cookie :P

Just don't know if its the best or most efficient way to do so

Answer (score 3):

As it's unique to each user, you could namespace the cache `key` to identify the user:

```
Cache::put('user_' . auth()->user()->id . '_posts',  $posts, 10);

or

cache(['user_' . auth()->user()->id . '_posts' => $posts], 10);
```

Then you can retrieve using:

```
Cache::get('user_' . auth()->user()->id . '_posts');

or

cache('user_' . auth()->user()->id . '_posts');
```

**Note:** If using laravel 5.8 the cache expiration is now in **seconds** and not minutes.

Comment: Won't it overload my system to keep that many big Variables on my Cache?

Comment: @Sp1deR This is assuming you will have loads of users on at one time. You can make sure this is reduced by `json_encode`'ing the `$posts`. Secondly, make sure `$posts` is an array and not an object/collection.

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks ! Still wondering if there is any smoother way to do so but it's good for now thanks for the help

Comment: @Sp1deR There probably will be with a change of approach. Please mark as correct.